# Symfony2 - Is an AdminBundle actually the correct way to organise the app?

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I'm new to Symfony and am starting an app which includes an admin section. The general advice is pretty obvious - make an AdminBundle.

However, is that really the best practice? The Symfony documentation is saying that a bundle is intended to be a 'plugin' that can be distributed as is, and will work in another app. Doesn't the admin section need to be aware of all the models and things for the main app though? It's an admin section created to administer changes specifically to my app, so how would it be distributable or self-contained?

I feel like I'm missing something because if all the advice is to make an AdminBundle then I obviously don't understand something or haven't delved far enough into Symfony yet.

I'm just looking to get my app started with the correct structure going forward.

FYI, I created a project with the default AppBundle as well. I was just planning to make everything in there, but that doesn't seem right either as it will be harder to organise all the admin stuff separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depeneds on tour needs and size of your project. Creating a special bundle to put there logic for of admin panel is a good practice. But if you have a small application with just couple of entities it's not necessary to create AdminBundle.

Symfony provides you any way you prefer to do what you need. You can create bundle or put all the admin panel business logic into special directory inside your main bundle controller directory or put all code into the same controllers and manage permissions to admin actions by setting up firewall.

I would suggest to use AdminBundle. It lets you keep your code cleaner: a client logic in one bundle, an admin logic is in another.

Bundle description taken from symfony official documentation isn't saying any opposite things. Because if you want you can use your AdminBundle in another app. Bundle is a way to keep different kind of business logic separated of each other.

Comment: OK, so now I have AdminBundle for the admin section of the site, and AppBundle for the normal part of the site a visitor would use or log in to. That doesn't make much sense to me really. The Admin is part of the app. At the same time though, I definitely feel it's better to separate all admin stuff into a bundle so it can have its own set of controllers, etc.

Comment: @BadHorsie You could think of the admin as a separate app. It might be operating on the same back-end data, but it's a separate interface for different users and a different purpose, with different logic and needs. In some ways what you've got is a user-facing app and an administration app, so separating them out doesn't feel too odd to me.

Comment: Regarding resources, the documentation is saying to put my resources for the AppBundle in `app/Resources/`. However, I would put my admin resources in `src/AdminBundle`. I feel like both bundles should follow the same convention. I would maybe put the front-facing website resources in `src/AppBundle`, the admin stuff in `src/AdminBundle`, then shared resources (e.g. jQuery, Bootstrap) in `app/Resources/public` - is that a good idea? What's the normal practice? And doesn't that violate the idea that AdminBundle is self-contained if it relies on resources not packaged with the bundle?

Comment: That's a good question. I think in your case - when you are going to use two bundles just to separate logic - you may wish to use jquery in both bundles, right? So, in this case you need to decide what is the base place for all shared assets. There is no single rule for that. It really depends on the project structure.

Comment: One more bundle? It's too much, I think

Comment: This must be a really common thing; I can't be the first person who has thought of this. So what is common practice amongst experienced Symfony2 devs, with regard to organising shared assets? Have you guys never had to think about this before?

Comment: I would keep all assets in AppBundle and in AdminBundle I would add them by {% javascripts '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}. Look more here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html.

Comment: So, @BadHorsie, what is your decision?

Comment: I think linking to the assets in another bundle doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I think it wouldn't make any sense if these bundles haven't been connected to each other. I think you will have only one entity directory and will call entity from both bundles. If one of these bundles was produced by some third-part vendor that would make sense, because it really would strange to call some assets from SonataAdminBundle in your bundle. After update everything can go wrong. In this case, yes, I agree. You can also keep common files in your web directory directly. Anyway all assets finally go there.